# Fundamental group of a wedge sum using SVK

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I am trying to prove that the fundamental group of a wedge sum is actually the free product of the fundamental groups.

I read Hatcher's proof Algebraic Topology, but he omits some points / leaves them as implicit.

Here is my proof :

Let $\Omega$, $\Lambda$ be disjoint spaces and $x_0 \in \Omega, \; y_0 \in \Lambda$. Assume $x_0$ (resp. $y_0$) is the deform retract of an open neighborhood  $U_{x_0}$ (resp. $U_{y_0}$) in $\Omega$ (resp. $\Lambda$). Let $A := \Omega \vee U_{y_0}$ and $B := \Lambda \vee U_{x_0}$. Since $\Omega$ and $\Lambda$ are disjoint, $A$ et $B$ are open, and besides $\Omega$ (resp. $\Lambda$) is retract deform of $A$ (resp. $B$) by the retract deform of $U_{y_0}$ into $\{y_0\} = \{x_0\}$ (resp. $U_{x_0}$ into $\{y_0\} = \{x_0\}$). And $A \cap B = U_{x_0} \vee U_{y_0}$ which deform retracts into the point $x_0$. Finally, $A \vee B$ deform retracts into $\Omega \vee \Lambda$.
Hence, according to Seifert - Van Kampen theorem :
$\pi_1(\Omega \vee \Lambda) = \pi_1(A \vee B) = \pi_1(A) \star_{\pi_1(A \cap B)} \pi_1(B) = \pi_1(\Omega) \star_{\{1\}} \pi_1(\Lambda) = \pi_1(\Omega) \star \pi_1(\Lambda)$.

Does it work ?

Especially I am not sure about the part "$A \vee B$ deform retracts into $\Omega \vee \Lambda$" : but without it I don't know how to conclude.

Thank you very much,

Respectfully,

AF

Comment: What hypotheses do you have on $\Omega,\Lambda$?

Comment: @FShrike They are path connected.

Comment: You don't need to consider $A \vee B,$ you need to consider $A \cup B$. But $A \cup B = \Omega \vee \Lambda$ so you're fine.

Comment: It works. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4625240.

Comment: @kamills your comment looks like an answer to me.